# C# WPF Update/Delete buttons do not work

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have an assignment to do Insert, Update and Delete operations in Northwind database upon Customers category. I managed to do the insert part and thought it's all done, as the code is supposed to be similar, but... I wrote Update by basically copying Insert and just changing the reference to stored procedure, but when I press the button, nothing happens. Code :

```
        private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=(local)");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateCustomer", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", "");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", companyName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", contactName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactTitle", contactTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalCode", zip);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phone);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region", "");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", "");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", "");

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

and my stored procedure for that was taken from MSDN :

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateCustomer]
    @CustomerID nchar(5),
    @CompanyName nvarchar(40),
    @ContactName nvarchar(30),
    @ContactTitle nvarchar(30),
    @Address nvarchar(60),
    @City nvarchar(15),
    @Region nvarchar(15),
    @PostalCode nvarchar(10),
    @Country nvarchar(15),
    @Phone nvarchar(24),
    @Fax nvarchar(24)
AS
UPDATE [dbo].[Customers]
   SET [CompanyName] = @CompanyName
      ,[ContactName] = @ContactName
      ,[ContactTitle] = @ContactTitle
      ,[Address] = @Address
      ,[City] = @City
      ,[Region] = @Region
      ,[PostalCode] = @PostalCode
      ,[Country] = @Country
      ,[Phone] = @Phone
      ,[Fax] = @Fax
 WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID
```

but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?
Also, do I need to do something with cascades in order to delete Customer, as those tables are sort of combined.

It's a basic project and I don't know any DataSets and stuff, so after searching 1000 websites I still cannot figure this one out.. :( Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform an `UPDATE` of a particular Customer, you will need to pass a `CustomerID`:

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", "");  <- Don't pass an empty string here..
```

[Not the cause of the problem, But I would investigate why you have the `CustomerID` column defined as `nchar(5)`]

Comment: Ok, I changed it to
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", companyID);
which I grab from CustomerID textbox, but nothing happens..

( It has to have length of 5 as it's set in Northwind Customers. When performing Insert, i take first 5 chars from Company Name. )

Comment: Ok I managed to make it work, but writing :

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", textBox_CompanyID.Text);

It somehow didn't pass it, which is wierd, as all the others worked fine.
Anyway, thank you!

Can you please tell me how to refresh ListBox after Insert/Update/Delete without any DataSets and stuff? It's a really simple project and I have no idea how to use any advanced stuff.
Any commands to clear and show new ListBox?

Thanks.

P.S. My reputation here is <10 and I cannot ask new question yet :)